# What's the fastest way to make a multiple field search in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I'm trying to achieve a really fast search engine for a MySQL db with several fields.

The problem relies on the fact that I need to match a value (keyword) against several fields, in a %like% approach.

I don't mind relevancy (the order is fixed), just performance. The queries are pretty complicated (lotta JOINS, 3 or 4 tables per query).

At first I thought of **MATCH ... AGAINST**, but I don't think it's a good idea to make so much FULLTEXT indexes. Maybe with PHP-generated **OR LIKE %value%**, but... is it really efficent?

Any ideas?

Comment: LIKE will certainly gonna take loads of time

Answer (score 2):

A `FULLTEXT` index - possibly just one spanning over all the columns you will query - is probably your very best bet. I imagine mySQL will be able to apply much better optimizations on this, and be way faster, than a plethora of `OR x LIKE y` statements.

Comment: Is that applicable to multiple tables? I mean, 5 or 6 fields are in the same table, but then there's a couple of fields taken from external tables, and I need to look for in that fields as well.

Thanks!

Comment: @Arthur nope, I don't think you can make an index expand across multiple tables.

Comment: Ops, sorry to hear that. Should I go back to OR %like%?

I'm very discouraged about this...

Comment: @Arthur why not put fulltext indexes on every table, and stick with `match against`? It's bound to be better than `LIKE` in any case.

Comment: Because just a few of those columns are var/char/text... what about a index wrapping all the searcheable fields in the table?